# Angular: I have an NgFor with an Index of loop, how can I assign the name of an element to be "myName+IndexOfLoop"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

So I have the following

```
<div *ngFor="let step of validationSteps; let i = index ">
<input matInput placeholder="SQL Query" name="sqlQuery" [(ngModel)]="validationSteps[i].sqlDetail.query">
 </div>
```

How can I make the name be "sqlQuery{loopOfIndexIHere}" with i appended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like with any other binding. Either using `{{i}}` on a normal attribute or using `[attr]="'name'+i"` on a bound attribute: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azynfb?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Your example would be one of the following:

```html
<div *ngFor="let step of validationSteps; let i = index ">
  <input matInput
    placeholder="SQL Query"
    name="sqlQuery{{i}}"
    [(ngModel)]="step.sqlDetail.query">
</div>
```

OR

```html
<div *ngFor="let step of validationSteps; let i = index ">
  <input matInput
    placeholder="SQL Query"
    [name]="'sqlQuery' + i"
    [(ngModel)]="step.sqlDetail.query">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be like this

```
[name]="'sqlQuery'+i"
```

Full code

```
<input matInput placeholder="SQL Query" [name]="'sqlQuery'+i" [(ngModel)]="validationSteps[i].sqlDetail.query">
```

Let me know if it work or not.

Comment: It does not. Error is r: Unexpected token 'i'